# isAjax() is deprecated method on CakePHP 2.0. What method substitute thats method?

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

This is my code

```
    function add() {
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        if($this->Post->save($this->data)) {
            if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){ //isAjax method is deprecated.
                //Handle Ajax
                $this->render('notif','ajax');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Add successfully');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));                    
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Add failded please try again');
        }
    }
}
```

Here i read that method is deprecated http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html?highlight=isajax

How to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says that CakeRequest is now responsible for that. You can find the appropriate paragraph here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#inspecting-the-request

```
function add() {
    if(!empty($this->request->data)) {
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            if($this->request->is('ajax')){ 
                //Handle Ajax
                $this->render('notif','ajax');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Add successfully');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));                    
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Add failded please try again');
        }
    }
}
```